# Ios Bluetooth Permission being denied react-native-permissions

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, react-native-permissions

My app is requesting the local network permission. After I click ok I see the bluetooth permissions rejected alert.

I have both `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` & `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` added to my `Info.plist`.

I have added `PERMISSIONS.IOS.BLUETOOTH_PERIPHERAL` from react-native-permissions while prompting bluetooth permission.

I have checked the `Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory` option under Background Modes in Xcode.

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.

The device is iPhone 11 & iOS 16.6

When I check Settings > My app > I dont see Bluetooth in the list and I'm unsure how to add the permission directly in Settings as well.

Comment: How do you request the permission? Did you test on device or simulator?

Comment: @MichaelBahl It was on a device. Will add more details

Answer (score 0):

- Based on the information you provided, it seems that the Bluetooth permission is not visible in the settings for your app on the iPhone 11 with iOS 16.6. However, you can manually add the Bluetooth permission in the device settings by following these steps:

1. Open the Settings app on your iPhone 11.
2. Scroll down and tap on "Privacy & Security".
3. Scroll down and tap on "Bluetooth".
4. Toggle on the switch for your app.

- NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothperipheralusagedescription
- If an app would like to use Bluetooth on your device : https://support.apple.com/en-us/102267
- Set up and use Bluetooth accessories on iPhone : https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph3c50f191/ios
- About privacy and Services in iOS, iPadOS, and watchOS : https://support.apple.com/en-us/102515